# How can I exec an interactive shell from Jython?

Tags: java, python, exec, jython, sh

I need some example Jython, or Java, code to exec an interactive OS shell (/bin/sh).  Our development environment is Java on Linux.  What I would like to do is provide a means for developers to write Jython scripts, and then drop into a shell, which allows them to inspect the system.  The reason I need to exec this from Jython or Java--as opposed to just wrapping all this in a shell script--is that we use Java load some libraries which I need to keep loaded while the interactive shell is running.  If the JVM were to terminate before the interactive shell runs, some of our custom hardware would be reset.

I have looked at the Jython subprocess module.  However, most of what I have seen will only run and wait on a subrocess to terminate (ie non-interactive).  None of the examples show how to the shell can be invoked interactively.  The same is true of most of the Java java.lang.Runtime.exec() examples I've seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is wrong with this simple jython code, is that the stdin, stdout do not work as we expect

```
import subprocess
import os          
subprocess.call([os.environ.get('SHELL', '/bin/sh'), '-i'])
```

Assuming that we want to spawn the shell on the tty, the following seems to
give better results:

```
import os
import subprocess

subprocess.call([os.environ.get('SHELL', '/bin/sh') +
    ' -i < /dev/tty > /dev/tty 2>&1'], shell=True)
```

This will run the shell within another subshell, that replaces the crippled stdin, stdout streams with the active tty.

Comment: When I run this, I see the shell prompt.  However, it does not appear to accept input.

Comment: hmm, then it means that your Jython does not set standard input properly. How do yourun your program? If I run jython 2.5.2 directly from command line, that works.

Comment: I'm running Jython 2.5.2, with Java 1.6.0_26-b03.  I tried running your example by both (1) pasting the lines into Jython interactive shell, and (2) by pass a script file to Jyton--same result.  In both cases, I started Jython using the ./jython shell script provided with the Jython 2.5.2 release.

Comment: Also, I just tried starting the Jython shell directly (without using the shell script file--ie java -jar jython.jar), and pasting in your example--same result.

Comment: Hmm, bash does not seem to work for me whereas zsh, my login shell, works.

Comment: I updated the code a bit, now it does indeed work for bash and zsh better

Comment: That works!!  One more quick question: any ideas on how to get a local echo of what is typed in the shell?  Many thanks, Antti!

Comment: I think Jython interactive shell line-editing code disables echoing too. Shells with advanced line-editing (bash, tcsh, zsh) actually disable the local echo and do echoing by themselves. You could use any of them, or try enabling echoing before executing the shell with "stty echo" command.

Comment: How to execute a simple shell script (Hello world) from jython code?